# How to check if a row has been updated and not inserted in android sqlite3

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database which i am inserting to.  Right now I have this code.

```
 database.insertWithOnConflict(FOO_TABLE, null, values,
            SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

This inserts into my database. Is there an efficient way to see if a row has been updated and not inserted with the constraint CONFILCT_REPLACE? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can compare returned _id with previously retrieved max(_id) - if _id > max(id) record was inserted, otherwise replaced.
Other way is a bit dumb - try to insert, in case of sql exception make update.